# Redirect to different view when selecting dropdown then click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a dropdown and a button where i do filtering. Once i select a value in dropdown, i click on the button to filter. This works fine. Below, the dropdown code and button code which is stored in my index.cshtml

```
   <div>
            <b>Show By Reference/Category:</b>
             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Reference, ViewBag.ISharedUI as SelectList, "-- REFERENCE TYPE --")


            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Filter" name="Command" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

the items in the dropdown works fine when filtering, but i have a problem where when selecting one value in dropdown called SCHEME, i need it to go to different view called indexscheme.cshtml. this is because the table structure is different to index.cshtml. below is how my controller looks like for filtering.

```
        public ActionResult Index(ListOfItems LOIForm, string Command)
    {


        //Dropdownlist for reference table
        List<CommonEntities> ISharedUI = CommonDAL.GetARSharedReference();
        ViewBag.ISharedUI = new SelectList(ISharedUI, "ID", "Description");

        if (Command == "Filter")
        {
            ListOfItems LOIT = new ListOfItems(); 
            LOIT = ARSharedDAL.GETID(LOIForm);
            return View(LOIT);

        }
        else
        {
            ListOfItems objListOfItemsDetails = new ListOfItems();
            objListOfItemsDetails = ARSharedDAL.GetTaskListInfo();   
            return View(objListOfItemsDetails);                 

        }
```

below is how my interface looks like. Filtering for other value works just fine. I just need it to go to different view when clicked on value SCHEME. So, how do i achieve this? im stuck for a while here. Any question and enquiry just ask. And please help in any way, i would really appreciate it. thanks guys.

[image]

Comment: `$('#yourSeletBoxId').on("change",function() {  //redirect }` ? clear me more

Comment: It's unclear from your controller code/view code. "Filtering" works fine because you've effectively hard-coded that value into your submit button (in other words `if (Command == "Filter")` will *always* be reached.) I'm assuming that's because you're using the same controller action to both load the page initially and *get* new data when the filter is applied... these should be two separate action methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#Reference").on("change", function() {
    if($("#Reference option:selected").text() == "SCHEME")
        window.location.href = '/YOURCONTROLLER/Index/' + YOUR_PARAMETERS;
});
```